# HTML Scraping with lxml and Requests

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I was doing like this tutorial, http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/, to scrap an html table and it doesn't work well.

My code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://www.dti.ufv.br/horario/horario.asp?ano=2015&semestre=1&depto=MAT')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

vaga = tree.xpath('/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[108]/td[9]')
print vaga
```

I think the problem is with XPath... I did it like the tutorial said using Google Chrome but it's not like in tutorial. Anyone can help me get the right XPath? Thanks guys!

Comment: Which row you want to target in HTML content?

Answer (score 1):

In HTML content, there is no `tbody` tag.

In code we are considering `tbody` tag to find target tag.

```
vaga = tree.xpath('/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[108]/td[9]')
```

This will always return empty list because `tbody` tag is not present in HTML content.

HTml content:

```
 <table width="760" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td><img src="img/topo.jpg" width="760" height="101"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td background="img/conteudo.jpg"><p align="right"><img src="img/setas_voltar.jpg" width="8" height="7"> <font size="1"><strong><a href="javascript:history.back();">voltar</a>&nbsp;</strong></font></p>
        <TABLE WIDTH=100% BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=1 CELLPADDING=1>
        <TR>
          <TD align=center> <br>
              <font color="Black" size=2><b> Hor&aacute;rio de Aulas 2015/1</b></font><br>          </TD>
        </TR>
      </TABLE>
```

Comment: Yea, but the Google Chrome returned that. How can i get the right XPath then? I want a right table from that page.

Comment: which row we want to target from the the table?? remove `tbody` form the xpath and try again. I do not know about   Google Chrome, I think Google Chrome will automatically insert `tbody` tag.

Comment: See 'MAT 135' second row? I want number 0's row. I want that number. It's left vacancies, and the number 65 is total vacancies. I want to process that number to see if there are vacancies yet to join MAT 135 class, thank you

Comment: @carlosza: not getting.. There are two row (`tr` tag) which first column(`td` tag) value is MAT 135 and its 8th column(`td` tag) have value `65`. We want to get these row (`tr` tag)??  Or can you shear what you want from this HTML content on my email vivekbsable@gmail.com. Pass me expected output of this HTML content if possible

Comment: @VivekSable thanks for the line _This will always return empty list because tbody tag is not present in HTML content._. It solved my problem.